# Universe V = Ultimate L inside set theoretic multiverse

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

Good day to you all,
I would like to ask a question about relation between Prof. H. Woodin V = Ultimate L and a concept of set theoretical multiverse as proposed by Prof. Hamkins.

If V = Ultimate L turns out to be true, does that mean that the whole set theoretic multiverse collapses? Or could the universe V = Ultimate L be just a maybe only little special universe inside much larger set theoretic multiverse?

Thank You for kind reply.

Comment: What do you mean "turns out to be true"? Truth is measured in a fixed model. Which model are we using here?

Comment: @AsafKaragila in the context of Woodins quest for ultimate inner model of V

Comment: In Steel's framework, we would say that V is a *core* of the multiverse.

Comment: In the multiverse proposed in my [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03169), this would just be one universe amongst many with the additional axiom Woodin proposes.